# Amazon EC2 Routes for mobile app

Tags: android, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

I have been trying for a while now.I have a Laravel application running on an EC2 Ubuntu instance. I want to make the routes available to update the database from a mobile application. How do I make the routes available to use in my android app to update the database? Where do I go and how to set it up? I read something before that this can be done in Route53 but not sure the process if any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are stuffs called APIs for that. If you know about it great enough or if you don't they are just kind of endpoints where two different service can talk with each other. 
You need to make proper APIs with Laravel for specific tasks that you need that API to do. Link those APIs if you can with API Gateway. API Gateway is a service of amazon for making your API globally accessible and also fast by its multi AZ Deployment.

Try to make sure your APIs are REST APIs , means they donot depend on sessions or any persistent connection properties like Sessions and stuff. If you want Authorization prefer using [JWT](http://jwt.io/) for the same.

Now on your Android code, make a request with the appropriate data to the endpoint for the stuff to happen, and wait for its response.

Comment: Thanks much going to look into API Gateway service. I already have the APIs just wanted to know where to setup the Amazon authentication so i can use them

Comment: Use API Gateway if you want the authentication service from Amazon, they have auth based on IAM Users and API Keys. Or else you can setup your own auth without API Gateway using JWT, it is one of the best Auth system out there for restful APIs